# Добавить и удалить класс элементу <a> по клику в цикле php

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот коды которые у меня есть
Вот html с php:

````
```<?$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menu");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
do{
$href = $row['title'];
if( $href == 'Home'){
$href = 'index';
}
if( $href == 'Contact Us'){
$href = 'contact';
}
?>
<a href="<?=$href?>.php" id="ahref" class="active"><?=$row['title']?>
<? }while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));?>

Вот javascript:
Вот css:
#templatemo_menu ul li a {
float: left;
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 26px;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #e4e1e1;
font-weight: bold;
outline: none;
border: none;
}
#templatemo_menu ul li a:hover, #templatemo_menu ul li .current {
color: #fff;
background: url(images/templatemo_menu_hover.jpg) center bottom no-repeat;
}```
````

Помогите, нужно чтобы при клике добавился класс current к нажатому

PS так как меню в цикле приходится делать операцию через js

Comment: По клину на что именно? (php тут ни к чему)  это вопрос по JS если по клику на ссылку. То будет происходить редирект на указаную страницу до того момента как скрипт выполниться. Если это действительно ссылки, а не кнопки

Comment: Вот html```<div id="templatemo_header">
<div id="site_title">
<h1><a href="index.html">
<img src="images/templatemo_logo.png" alt="tripod blog" /></a>
<span>free blog template</span>
</h1>
</div>
<div id="templatemo_rss">
<a href="" target="_parent">SUBSCRIBE<br /><span>OUR FEED</span></a>
</div>
 </div>``` По клику на <a> должен добавиться class current (смотрите в css). Вот js: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a').click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('current');
});
}); 
</script>

Comment: Элемент который не должен перенаправлять пользователя на другую страницу должен быть кнопкой. Твой код будет работать правильно, если ты ссылки заменишь на button / и добавишь им нужные классы . Будет выглядеть примерно так  $(document).ready(function() { $('.my-button').click(function() { $(this).addClass('current'); }); });

Comment: Без замены <a> на <button> можно построить код?